# Buffer issue cannot use <type> as type io.Reader in argument to http.NewRequest golang

Tags: go, buffer, httprequest

I was having an issue when I was passing string in http.NewRequest in golang body param.

The error I got was :

> cannot use req.Body (type string) as type io.Reader in argument to
>   http.NewRequest:
>           string does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)

Similarly there are other use cases where the Buffer is required as an input instead of a particular type or an array of it. 
eg, byte[] when input required is buffer.

What did the error mean and what are ways of solving it and understanding what golang is trying to enforce.

Edit: This was the line I was having an issue with and did not find any references.

> http.NewRequest(req.Method, req.Url, req.Body)

http.NewRequest(req.Method, req.Url, strings.NewReader(req.Body)) solves the issue.
I was planning to add the answer as well (as an FYI type of question)

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Already mentioned that the error was in http.NewRequest when giving the body as string.

Comment: Can anyone tell, why the downvote to question? I did not find any references of such question on the forum.

Comment: @Prateek In the world of SO, juniors can not ask questions, only seniors with 10 years of experience and perfect questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error means that the `http.NewRequest` method take a `io.Reader` interface as its `body` argument:

```
func NewRequest(method, urlStr string, body io.Reader) (*Request, error)
```

It is done this way so you can pass a file, a connection to a server, the response from something else to the request easily.

The "problem" is that a `string` doesn't implement the `io.Reader` interface, which is defined as follow:

```
type Reader interface {
   Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

Its not a huge problem, you can use the `strings.Reader` type which is a wrapper around a `string` that implement the said interface.

```
func NewReader(s string) *Reader
```

Tip: There also is a `bytes.Reader` type for the times you have a `[]byte` to pass as parameter.